# How to show two sets with different numbers of degrees of freedom are different?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Suppose there are two smooth injective functions
$$f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^p \text{ and } g:\mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^p, $$
where $m\neq n$. 
The domains of $f$ and $g$ are Cartesian products of intervals:
$$D(f) = \times_{k=1}^{n}(a_k,b_k) \text{ and }D(g) = \times_{k=1}^{n}(c_k,d_k),$$
where $a_k,b_k,c_k,d_k \in [-\infty,+\infty]$. Is it possible to prove that the images of $f$ and $g$ are different, i.e.
$$I(f) \neq I(g)?$$

Comment: Yes, $I(f) \neq I(g)$ because homeomorphisms preserve the dimension of manifolds. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355244/homeomorphic-manifolds-have-the-same-dimension